# How to create a window in dark mode using WinApi/Win32 in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, window, darkmode

Result of my Code:

[image: Result of my Code]

Create Button Code:

```cpp
// Create Button
dwStyle = (WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON);
HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(
    L"BUTTON",                                             // Predefined class; Unicode assumed
    L"OK",                                                 // Button text
    dwStyle,                                               // Styles
    10,                                                    // x position
    10,                                                    // y position
    70,                                                    // Button width
    30,                                                    // Button height
    hwndMain,                                              // Parent window
    NULL,                                                  // No menu.
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwndMain, GWLP_HINSTANCE), // Instance handle
    NULL                                                   // Pointer not needed.
);
```

For Top Bar Dark Code:

```cpp
DWORD value = TRUE;
DwmSetWindowAttribute(hwndMain, DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE, &value, sizeof(value));
```

My expectation was that the button and text box would also be in dark mode. If there is no way to do this automatically, how to do this manually? For example, how do I create a button from scratch with the colors I want?

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, be sure to [enable Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview).

According to [Application Requirements for Supporting Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/visual-styles-overview#application-requirements-for-supporting-visual-styles):

> For common controls, no further action is necessary to ensure that the controls are displayed in the user's preferred visual style.
>
> If your application contains custom or owner-drawn controls, you need to use the visual styles API to retrieve information about the currently active visual style, and to draw the controls in that style.

Then, because the light theme and the dark theme both refer to the **same** [.msstyles files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/themesfileformat-overview#visual-styles-section), which is for **backward compatibility support for Windows Classic theming mode**, their appearances are the same.

[**In Windows 8 and later, high contrast mode has been modified to work with Visual Styles**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/what-s-new-for-windows-8#windows-8-and-later).

The following picture shows controls supporting High Contrast Themes in Windows 11:

[image]

Comment: It worked with High Contrast Theme, though, how do you make the button dark without this high-contract mode?

Comment: And in Windows8 and later, using Visual styles to change appearance doesn't work no more but you **may** let Theme (.theme) files point to different .msstyles files which make appearance different.

Comment: [msstyleEditor](https://github.com/nptr/msstyleEditor) can edit Windows Vista, 7, 8, 10 and 11 visual styles (.msstyles files). Note, in order to apply the visual styles, it needs extra effort.

Comment: @GabrielFrigo [msstyleEditor](https://github.com/nptr/msstyleEditor) is used to custom visual styles (.msstyles files). Then you can make the dark mode theme file point to the .msstyles file. Note, in order to apply the visual styles, it needs extra effort.