# Supporting dark mode for MFC dialog application (DwmSetWindowAttribute)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, dialog, darkmode

I might be going about this all wrong, but I stumbled on this article:

[Support Dark and Light themes in Win32 apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-windows-themes)

I followed the steps:

1/

```
#include <dwmapi.h>
```

2/

```
#ifndef DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE
#define DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE 20
#endif
```

3/

Call in `InitInstance`:

```
BOOL value = TRUE;
::DwmSetWindowAttribute(m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd(),
                        DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE, 
                        &value, sizeof(value));
```

As you can see, I am using a `CDialog` based application.

4/ I added `Dwmapi.lib`.

It compiles fine. But when I run my application the title bar is *not* dark. Why?

A related question is that in the article it states:

> This article provides examples of ways to detect system theme changes, and request a light or dark title bar for your Win32 application's window. *It does not cover specifics of how to repaint and render your app UI using a Dark mode color set*.

So how do we go about this for an MFC Dialog application?

Note that my Windows 11 PC is running in Dark Mode.

Comment: Are you running Windows 11 Build 22000 or more?

Comment: @SimonMourier I am running the latest release. Performed Windows Updates today. Build 22621.1105.

Comment: Apparently, dark mode isn't supported for dialogs. If you open File Explorer and go to *View* -> *Options*, that dialog is using the Light theme, even when the system is configured to use Dark theme by default.

Comment: @IInspectable Annoying. I like the dark theme. I like Zooms dark theme. This article implied we could do it. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd()` returns `NULL` if run in `InitInstance` as window is not created yet. Try `OnInitDialog` and it will work.

Comment: OK, it does compile is I run it from `OnInitDialog`. But all it does is set the title bar to dark. Nothing else.

Comment: Dark title is all what `DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE` does. You can switch some controls to dark mode using `SetWindowTheme` with `DarkMode_Explorer`, but not all controls supported and sometimes you need additional tweaks for scrollbars. Some controls do not have dark theme support at all. For example we ended up drawing Tab Control manually because of lack of support by Windows.

Comment: Sure. It's a real pity there is no official support for this. Thanks for your answer anyway. And sorry it took me four months to accept. 

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it is achievable for common controls such as dialog boxes.

It will use the themes file.
[image]

[[Visual Styles] Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/themesfileformat-overview#visual-styles-section) shows a VisualStyles section for a High Contrast Black theme.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74693130/how-to-create-a-window-in-dark-mode-using-winapi-win32-in-c/74697614#74697614) has implemented it. It may help.

Comment: Thanks. But I was only able to get the existing Visual Styles Manager to function with SDI / MDI applications and not Dialog applications. The linked discussion refers to visual styles. It is a pity there is no existing worked sample for MFC dialog applications to support dark mode using native dark theme skin of Windows 11.